# Find out external command runability

Tags: external, raku

How to check whether an external program is available for running via Raku?
In shell, `type` command is to be used, e.g:

```sh
if type trash-put
then trash-put delete-me
else rm delete-me
fi
```

You can't `run 'type', 'trash-put'` in Raku since `type` is a shell builtin.
You can, though, `run 'sh', '-c', 'type trash-put'` or `shell 'type trash-put'`, so Raku equivalent would be:

```
if ! run( 'sh', '-c', 'type trash-put', :!out ).exitcode {
# if ! shell( 'type trash-put', :!out ).exitcode { # shell alternative to run
  run 'trash-put', 'delete-me';
} else {
  unlink 'delete-me'.IO;
}
```

but I wonder whether there are any better ways.

The question is not constrained to deleting files, other use-cases need an answer too: prefer `curl` over `wget` or browser1 over browser2 or `$VISUAL` over `$EDITOR` etc.

Comment: I am not sure about Raku, but the Perl 5 module [IPC::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Cmd) has a method `can_run()`. See also [this](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=761662) discussion for some ideas

Comment: Knowing you can run `curl` or `wget` isn't sufficient because on windows those commands are often default mapped to a powershell http request client without also mapping their interface (i.e. curl options won't be understood). In zef we have a small wrapper around each command that checks the output of a known `--help` flag (which avoids the example windows curl problem mentioned earlier).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using [Inline::Perl5](https://github.com/niner/Inline-Perl5) and the `can_run()` sub routine from the Perl 5 module [IPC::Cmd](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Cmd):

```
use v6;
use IPC::Cmd:from<Perl5> <can_run>;
my $cmd = 'wget';
if (my $exec = can_run($cmd)) {
    say "Path to {$cmd} : $exec";
}
else {
    say "{$cmd} was not found in PATH";
}
```

**Output on my machine**:

```
Path to wget : /bin/wget
```

Comment: .oO ( »ö« .oO ( I ❤️ Perl. While I'm big into metamorphosis, I love seeing Rakoons who humbly, spiritually, technically, practically, and gratefully *build on Perl*. We literally technically can't build Rakudo without Perl. And with good reason; Perl is *still* a great tool for so much OS specific functionality, especially probing and building functionality. And Perl is *still* the community from which I sprang. So I *love* it when Stefan's Inline::Perl works. Its use is not just easy and sensible, but open source community collaboration at its finest. That truly warms my little heart! ) )

Comment: fwiw even this technically isn't a complete solution since built-ins e.g. `type` won't be found with it. However if such a solution is sufficient there is `Zef::Utils::FileSystem::which("...")` which saves a bit on dependencies.